# Scala naming convention for Futures

Tags: scala, naming-conventions, future

What is the naming convention in Scala for function returning result wrapped in Future? I have seen code like:

```
getResult
getResultF
getResultFtr
```

Or even

```
getResultFuture
```

If there is no specific convention then I would like to know what is practiced more.

Comment: Do not use something like `getX` for something which takes time. Use `fetchX: Future[X]`. Using `getX` for a long running call is not a very good idea. so use `fetchX`, `computeX`, `calculateX`, `generateX` instead.

Comment: No specific convention

Comment: I'd use `getResultFuture`, but it's just personal preference AFAIK. I've never come across a consensus on the "proper" way to name Futures.

Answer (score 4):

I usually don't name methods returning `Futures` any differently. My reason is that this information is already present in the return type, and will be made clear by any decent IDE upon autocompletion.

One exception is in the presence of another similar method that doesn't return a `Future` but does everything synchronously. In that case, I like to clearly differentiate them:

```
def fooSync: A
def fooAsync: Future[A]
```

That's a pattern I've seen in plenty of libraries.